React state does not update in component loaded at runtime
I have a component whose js file I load dynamically into a target repo. I load this the js file at runtime by adding a script tag that points to the file as the page loads.
I also have react state that I want to pass to the component built into the js file such that the component will track the state object.
Here is how define and export the component in the remote repo:
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

interface RemoteCompProps {
  text: string;
  setText: (value: string) => void;
}

function RemoteComp({ text, setText }: RemoteCompProps) {
  console.log("text (in remote comp):\n", text);
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={text}
      onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
}

export interface AssetExportConfig {
  remoteCompProps: RemoteCompProps;
  domId: string;
}

export const assetExport = {
  renderToDOM: (config: AssetExportConfig) => {
    createRoot(document.getElementById(config.domId) as HTMLElement).render(
      <RemoteComp {...config.remoteCompProps} />
    );
  },
  assetName: 'Remote-Comp'
};

This is how I load the js file built from the above component:
const ASSET_URL = 'http://localhost:5173/ext-assets';
const ASSET_NAME = 'Remote-Comp';
const EXT_COMP_ID = 'aBC123';

const loadAsset = () => {
    const scriptId = `script-${ASSET_NAME}`;
    let script = document.getElementById(`script-${ASSET_NAME}`) as HTMLScriptElement;
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = `${ASSET_URL}/${ASSET_NAME}.js`;
    script.id = scriptId;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
};

export function LocalPage() {
    loadAsset();
    const [text, setText] = useState('First');

    const extCompElement = window[ASSET_NAME];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (extCompElement) {
            extCompElement?.assetExport?.renderToDOM({
                remoteCompProps: {
                    text,
                    setText,
                },
                domId: EXT_COMP_ID,
            });
        }
    }, [extCompElement]);

    console.log('text (in local comp):\n', text);

    return (
        <div>
            <div id={EXT_COMP_ID} />
            <button onClick={() => setText('First')}>Reset text</button>
        </div>
    );
}

So I expect text to be updated in both the remote component and the local one when it is changed either through click the reset button in the local component or when typing in the input field in the remote component.
Although the remote component loads successfully in the local component and the text state is updated in the local component when text is type in the input field (in the remote component), the value displayed in the input field (in the remote component) when clicking the rest button in the local repo.
The text state does get update locally when clicking the button in the local repo, but state is updated in the remote component. Update the input field in remote component does, however, update the text state locally.
Could it be because of the manual rendering of the remote component? Is there a way to update the state in the remote component too?

The remote component does not re-render with the new value of text because the effect to render the component in the DOM runs only on mount or when the extCompElement changes. i.e. it isn't configured to run when text is changed.
Here are some suggestions:

Add text to the dependency array of the effect so that the effect is re-run

    useEffect(() => {
        if (extCompElement) {
            extCompElement?.assetExport?.renderToDOM({
                remoteCompProps: {
                    text,
                    setText,
                },
                domId: EXT_COMP_ID,
            });
        }
    }, [extCompElement, text]);


Introduce internal state in the Remote component and an effect to setText when this internal state changes.

function RemoteComp({ text, setText }: RemoteCompProps) {
  const [internalText, setInternalText] = useState(text);
  console.log("text (in remote comp):\n", internalText);
  useEffect(() => {
      setText(internalText);
  }, [internalText]);
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={internalText}
      onChange={(event) => setInternalText(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
}


Solution 1 does update the text but the problem is that the root is re-created causing the whole component to keep being created even when editing the text in the input itself.

Solution 2 still has the same problem where ReactComp still does not get the updated text field when changed from the local component.

Yes, that's a drawback with the Solution 1. It performs poorly with components that are frequently interacted with.  Do you set the input value to internalText when working with Solution 2 or text? ReactComp will not get the updated text field because it's a passed prop whose value is determined at the time of rendering.

text does get updated in the local repo. But the prop in the remote component is not updated. I am starting to think of using a state manager like zustand

Building on Solution 1, have you thought about refactoring renderToDom to accept a React root instead of a document ID? This way, rendering the component with new props wouldn't necessitate recreating the entire component.

Awesome idea. Trying it out. A more convenient way of rendering the component can help.
